# In pandas crosstab, how to calculate weighted averages? And how to add row and column totals?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, categorical-data

I have a pandas dataframe with two categorical variables (in my example, city and colour), a column with percentages, and one with weights.
I want to do a crosstab of city and colour, showing, for each combination of the two, the weighted average of perc.

I have managed to do it with the code below, where I first create a column with weights x perc, then one crosstab with the sum of (weights x perc), another crosstab with the sum of weights, then finally divide the first by the second.

It works, but **is there a quicker/more elegant way to do it?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df=pd.DataFrame()
myrows=10
df['weight'] = np.random.rand(myrows)*100

np.random.seed(321)
df['perc']=np.random.rand(myrows)
df['weight x perc']=df['weight']*df['perc']
df['colour']=np.where( df['perc']<0.5, 'red','yellow')

np.random.seed(555)
df['city']=np.where( np.random.rand(myrows) <0.5,'NY','LA' )


num=pd.crosstab( df['city'], df['colour'], values=df['weight x perc'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
den=pd.crosstab( df['city'], df['colour'], values=df['weight'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)

out=num/den

print(out)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here using a groupby with apply() and using the numpy weighted average method.

```
df.groupby(['colour','city']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.perc, weights=x.weight)).unstack(level=0)
```

which gives

```
colour       red    yellow
city                      
LA      0.173870  0.865636
NY      0.077912  0.687400
```

I don't have All on the margin though.

This will produce the totals

```
df.groupby(['colour']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.perc, weights=x.weight))
df.groupby(['city']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.perc, weights=x.weight))
```

Granted still not packaged into a single frame

Comment: Thanks. I need the totals, so my approach might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm found a solution now ! YES!
I'm a beginner in programming, my code run but it can be improved, it's sure.
I hope it can help somebody.
Thank you, everybody, for your help.

> 

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df=pd.DataFrame()
myrows=10
df['weight'] = np.random.rand(myrows)*100

np.random.seed(321)
df['perc']=np.random.rand(myrows)
#df['weight x perc']=df['weight']*df['perc']
df['colour']=np.where( df['perc']<0.5, 'red','yellow')

np.random.seed(555)
df['city']=np.where( np.random.rand(myrows) <0.5,'NY','LA' )

df.head()
```

and the tab creation :

```
grouped = df.groupby(['colour','city'])
ci = df.groupby('city')
co =df.groupby('colour')

def wavg(group):
    d = group['perc']
    w = group['weight']
    return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()

# adding 1 columns of aggregate the weighted average by row
result = pd.concat([grouped.apply(wavg).unstack(level=0),ci.apply(wavg).rename('weighted average')],axis = 1)
# change index because unstack get city is index, i want city in columns
result.index.name='city'
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
# adding 1 row in bottom of aggregate the weighted average by columns and weighted average of the dataframe (total)
# be careful about co.ndim i'm not sure is alway ok
result.loc['WAvg'] = ['weighted average'] + [co.apply(wavg).values.round(1)[i] for i in range(0,co.ndim)] + [((df['perc'] * df['weight']).sum() / df['weight'].sum()).round(1)] 
result
```

see the résult :

[I had this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXAdq.png)